# Wifi on macbookpro 13,3 (15" Late 2016)

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, macbook-pro, apple

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS; and Debian, using `iwd`, `systemd-networkd`, `systemd-resolved`.

I have tried to follow the instructions [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=193121) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers), but to no avail.

The most I can do is view available networks, either in the gnome graphical interface or `iwctl`. Trying to connect to the networks will fail.

I've created a file for my own future reference reference [here](https://gitlab.com/JohnCorbs/macbookpro-13-3), in an attempt to explain my thinking and what I have tried. In short, I believe the problem to be that `bcrmfmac` cannot find the file `brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.clm_blob`, and regardless of having the `.txt` and `.bin` file.

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: I apologize about the confusion. I created the gitlab with the intention of writing out how I installed Debian onto my MacBook, a future reference to myself as I generally prefer using Debian. I attempted the changes in both the links I provided above, and got the same results listed in the Gitlab, on both the Debian and Ubuntu installs. I tried on an instance of Ubuntu afterwards purely because I thought I was missing something with my debian install. Below is the output of uname -a on both:

Comment: Debian: `Linux debianMacBook 6.1.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.55-1 (2023-09-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux`    Ubuntu:`Linux userMacBookUbuntu 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  9 15:34:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: I apologize again, its 22.04 that I have not 20.04